# Why least active metals have highest conductivity

Tags: electricity, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, electrochemistry

Metals like copper, gold,silver hold the lowest spot in chemical reactivity series ie; they show more tendency to get reduced than any other metal; but in terms of electrical conductivity they hold the highest spots. ***I seek for a well defined relation between activity of metal and it's electrical conductivity and also want to know why least active metals show highest conductivity.***

Comment: Electrical conductivity of the crystal and tendency to be reduced are really really hard to link in any direct fashion. Copper silver and gold have beautiful near-free-electron Bloch functions. Now, aluminum is the next most-conductive metal (then calcium and tungsten). So, I'd say there is no well defined relation.

Comment: First I would perhaps connect higher conductivity to high reactivity, in the sense of "loose electrons", not the viceversa. Both ways, think of oxidation potential (or reduction, if you wish) as elemental properties, and conductivity as a bulk properties. Work-function does indeed correlates to red. pot., it seems the proper comparison as it is indeed removal of electrons.